# How to check a date in mysql using other field of the same table

Tags: mysql, date

i explain better my question:

i have a table like:

```
|ID|DATE|DAYS|
```

users in my site could search for a range of date inside my db, so i need to check if min date that users select is greater than the date in column `DATE` and if `DATE` forward `DAYS` is lower or equal to max date that users select. Is there a way to to that? can someone help me? Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try below:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE date < 'your_input_min_date' 
  AND 'your_input_max_date' >= DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL days DAY)
```